# Removing bugspray from painted surface

Tags: paint, chemicals

My wife spilled bugspray over this window ledge, which is wood covered with a layer of primer and two layers of interior semi-gloss.

[image]

It seems impossible so far to remove the bugspray. The paint feels like it's melting and is gooey to the touch. After cleaning it with water and sanding with an orbital sander, I re-primed the affected surface but the bugspray ate through the new coat as well, melted it and basically it remained in a gooey state.

How do I remove bugspray from a painted surface?

Comment: Is that plywood we're seeing in the exposed area, or is that the milky remains of the bug spray/paint combo?

Comment: I think that's the primer

Answer (score 2):

At this point, all you can do is get some paint/finish remover and remove everything from the surface. Then give it a good sanding, re-prime and paint. Doing the whole top will be faster than just trying to fix the damaged area and matching the finish.

Comment: And use an alkyd primer like Kilz Original. It is more likely to be stable over chemicals.

Answer (score 1):

**Flip it?**

Remove the whole thing and flip it upside-down.  Then paint the new top.  Bugspray probably did not soak thru the whole thing.  Structurally it is sound.  Bugspray damage will not attract attention on the bottom side.

Comment: removing it is PIA because I used finish screws that have wood filler over them